# What is the typescript type for columnDefs callback functions?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a columnDefs declaration that looks as following:

```
constColumnDefs = [
{headerName: 'a', field:'a', valueGetter: myValueGetter, ....
]
```

So when defining myValueGetter function, whats the type for params?
I am using "any" and it works, but I would like to make it more "typescripty"

```
const myValueGetter = function(params: any) {
   if (!params || !params.data) {
       return null;
   }
   etc....
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `valueGetter` is as below.

```
valueGetter?: ((params: ValueGetterParams) => any) | string;
```

If you are curious about `ValueGetterParams`, its as below.

```
export interface ValueGetterParams extends BaseColDefParams {
    getValue: (field: string) => any;
}
export interface BaseColDefParams {
    node: RowNode;
    data: any;
    colDef: ColDef;
    column: Column;
    api: GridApi;
    columnApi: ColumnApi;
    context: any;
}
```

You can find it inside `colDef.d.ts` file of the [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) node_module.

Comment: thank you. I have found the file in node_modules\ag-grid\src\ts --- so how do I pull it into my code?  I have tried importing from ag-grid, but I dont think I am doing it right.  Thanks again

Comment: What's wrong in that? You are doing perfectly right! PS: up vote if u think this helped u, mark it as answer if this solves ur problem